# What is the name of flutter output files in Linux?

Tags: flutter, flutter-linux

I need to know the name of all destination files and folders that current version of stable flutter will create after building project on Linux(for example Ubuntu) by this command:

```
flutter build linux
```

I just need to know the name of files that are necessary to run the application on another Linux system.

Answer (score 1):

The build files are inside: `/build/linux/x64/release/bundle`

Comment: Thank you and I know it! but I need to know the name of files not directory, specially dynamic linking library files.